# Can you filter an ICollectionView in an UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, filter, gridview, uwp

I'm still learning C# by developing a small UWP app.
Basically my app fetches my owned Steam games and adds them asynchronously to an ObservableCollection. Which adds the games to the Gridview.

XAML:

```
<GridView
    x:Name="BasicGridView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTemplate}"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemClick="BasicGridView_ItemClick"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    Margin="15, 0, 0, 0"
>
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 15, 15, 0"/>
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
</GridView>
```

C# code:

```
// My games list
public ObservableCollection<Game> OwnedGames { get; set; }

// Binding my games list to the GridView
BasicGridView.DataContext = OwnedGames;
```

Now my next step is to add filtering.
After some search, it seems a solution is to use a CollectionViewSource.

This is what I ended up with:

```
public ICollectionView OwnedGamesView { get; set; }

CollectionViewSource OwnedGamesViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
OwnedGamesViewSource.Source = OwnedGames;
OwnedGamesView = OwnedGamesViewSource.View;
```

Since I would use a CollectionView now, I changed the Datacontext of the GridView like this:

```
BasicGridView.DataContext = OwnedGamesView;
```

When running the app, everything still works like this, so the last step would have been to perform the filtering itself:

```
OwnedGamesView.Filter(...);
```

However this method doesn't exist in my case.
It isn't listed on the ICollectionView API reference for UWP:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.icollectionview?view=winrt-20348

So I am wondering how I can still make this work within an UWP app?
Or what a possible alternative is?

I hope my question is clear?
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However this method doesn't exist in my case. It isn't listed on the ICollectionView API reference for UWP

`ICollectionView` does not contain `Filter`, for your requirement, you could use `Microsoft.Toolkit`  [AdvancedCollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/advancedcollectionview) class to approach. It contains `Filter` property, you could use it to filter the collection and set `SortDescriptions`.

```
var acv = new AdvancedCollectionView(oc);

// Let's filter out the integers
int nul;
acv.Filter = x => !int.TryParse(((Person)x).Name, out nul);

// And sort ascending by the property "Name"
acv.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", SortDirection.Ascending));

// AdvancedCollectionView can be bound to anything that uses collections. In this case there are two ListViews, one for the original and one for the filtered-sorted list.
RightList.ItemsSource = acv;
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem and was easy to implement! :)

Answer (score 0):

Filtering using a `CollectionViewSource` is not done on the resulting `View` collection, but the `CollectionViewSource` instance itself. Add an event listener to the `CollectionViewSource.Filter` event. See an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter?view=net-5.0#examples).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. However as you can see in the link below, the Filter event doesn't even exist. Also I was wondering from where/when this Filter event would have been fired? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource?view=winrt-20348

Comment: I see. In that case you may be better off binding directly to an `ObservableCollection` and performing the filtering yourself with an in-memory cache of the original list to filter against. This can be done using a simple `Where` LINQ query.

Comment: This is a good solution, however I used AdvancedCollectionView.
However your solution, was one I thought about, and would be better for compatibility with older Windows versions.